# OCAML Recursive function not stopping

Tags: recursion, ocaml, ml

And thanks for your help. I'm currently working on an assigment, and I've been stuck with a faulty recursive call.
I have a simple CAML-Light function which is supposed to take a list and a size (number), and return a list with a chunk of that list, of that size, and a list with the rest. Really simple actually, it's a translation from a past PLT-Scheme project.

However, I'm having trouble with the recursive call. I simply don't know why it's not working. The function goes like this:

```
let rec cortar texto longitud resultado = match texto, longitud with
            |  _::t,0 -> resultado::(t::[])
            |  c::t,x-> cortar t (longitud-1) (consderecha resultado c);;
```

Longitud is the integer which defines the size. I'm afraid I'm doing something terribly wrong, as it appears to loop infinitely because "longitud" never reaches 0. I'm (as you may guess) new to ML and it's dialects, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Solved it, actually not really... Turns out I was calling the function with commas on the list, rather than semicolons. Yep. So thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer because I see so many problems with the code.

You say your function takes a list and a size, but the function you're defining here takes three parameters. It appears that the `resultado` parameter is an accumulated result. It's a little untidy to add this parameter to your outer function. Generally you'd want to add it to an internal function so the outer function matches your description (i.e., it takes two parameters).

Both of your patterns in the `match` statement assume that `texto` is non-null. This means your pattern isn't exhaustive, i.e., the function will fail if `texto` is null either initially or in a recursive call.

Your function uses a function named `consderecha` that's not defined anywhere. I'm going to assume it does a reverse cons, i.e., it adds a value to the end of a list. (This is not a good way to handle lists. Adding a value to the end of a list is slow.)

However, if you put aside all these issues, I don't see any problem with your recursion. When I try your function on a case where it's defined, it almost works. (It seems to be missing a value from the middle of the list.)

```
# cortar [1;2;3;4;5] 2 [];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [4; 5]]
```

Possibly rather than not stopping, your function isn't starting. Maybe you forgot the third parameter?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Yeah, I'm aware of the first issue ^^ I use it exclusively for it being called from another function, but you're right, I should fix that. "Consderecha does exactly that, appending with @ an element to the end of the list. I'm also aware it's not the best way, but it's the only one I can think of. I was, amazingly foolishly, forgetting that ML separates elements on a list with ; and not with ,. Yep, that was it, believe or not T_T.

Comment: So, thanks for your help, and I'm really sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the advice, as well!

Comment: It is my pleasure, I don't consider my time wasted.